# start making 2D game in Android from Beginner level

Tags: android

I have an game idea and i wants to implement that in android.

My game has much similarity with [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.g6677.android.phairsalon&hl=en) game

please tell me which game engine i need to use to make this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more and i think best option to create game application in android using **cocos2D** library. This library is highly customized and easy to learn than AndEngine. Because i have worked with AndEngine library but it is not efficiently handle more then 300 objects on a  scene. And one more limitation of AndEngine is sometime library itself throws error.So i suggesting you to use **COCOS2D** library it is already efficiently work in iPhone. But it also works for Android.You can see at
 http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/ 
for android and for more concept of this library you can see from this link       http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Getting_Started

Comment: Super nice, i indeed wants such kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of open source engines you can use like [AndEngine](http://www.andengine.org/) and [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) which is my preference, also there is the famous [Unity Engine](http://unity3d.com/) however it's not free. To learn how to make games you'll have to start simple, you can read through game examples like this [libGDX clone of Doodle Jump](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/superjumper) or [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos/metagun) 2D game demo written by Notch the creator of Minecraft.

Use Google to find information on these engines, look at their forums, tutorials and examples. Good luck.

Comment: i like AndEngine , Thank yoy